# isomorphic properties

Tags: banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I need help with this proof:

When $L$ is a isomorphic (bijection) linear mapping between two Banach spaces , in the case of both the spaces are Hilbert when using $L$, is it right to say that the Hilbert spaces keeps the isomorpic properties : $\langle x,y\rangle  =  \langle Lx,Ly\rangle $ ?

Thank in advance .

Comment: TeX tip: Use `$\langle x,y\rangle$` to get $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is ‘no’. We need $ L $ to be an **isometry**. By letting $ x = y $ in the identity above, we obtain
$$
\| x \|^{2} = \langle x,x \rangle = \langle L(x),L(x) \rangle = \| L(x) \|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, $ L $ preserves the norm of any vector, which implies that $ L $ is a norm-preserving linear mapping. Such a mapping is called a **linear isometry**.

There exist isomorphisms that are not linear isometries. For example, the linear operator that arises from multiplying a vector by a non-zero scalar with absolute value $ \neq 1 $ is a non-isometric isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a huge difference between linear isomorphism; linear homeomorphism; and linear isometry.

The former simply preserves one structure: the vector space structure. Not the norm, not the topology, not anything.

The second is a linear bijection which is also compatible with the topology, so it is an isomorphism of both vector spaces and topological spaces.

The third is not only a linear homeomorphism, but it also preserves the norm itself, and by extension the inner product when it exists.

---

To see that there is a difference, note that $\ell^2$ and $\ell^\infty$ are both of the same [Hamel] dimension, so there is a linear isomorphism between them, but it cannot be continuous because the topologies are very different: $\ell^2$ is a separable Hilbert space, whereas $\ell^\infty$ is non-separable and not a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I'm little bit confused with all 'isomorphism' definitions. Now, in the case of isometric isomorphism how I can show that identity above is true for every $x,y \in H $ when $H$ is Hilbert ?

Comment: Isomorphism means that the map preserves structure. But it is often implicit what is the structure being preserved. Just saying "linear" is not enough information, and in fact it hints that a lot of the structure might *not* be preserved (e.g. it is possible that this is a very discontinuous isomorphism). If we assume that the isomorphism is an isometry then by definition the norm is preserved. Use the fact that the norm induces the inner product (using that identity) and conclude that the inner product must be preserved as well.